# How to fix repetitives names & ids in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I have a HTML generated by another app that has some inconsistencies:

```
<a href="#_ftn1" name="_ftnref1">some link</a>

<div id="ftn1">
    content
</div>

<a href="#_ftn1" name="_ftnref1">another link</a>

<div id="ftn1">
    another content
</div>
```

As you can see I have a inconsistency here cause the id "**ftn1**" has been used twice. Same for name **_ftnref1**.

So I would like to know if there is a lib or a native way to fix those repetitives id and names in a way to "increment" their numbers and avoid the repetition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this html generated by php?

Comment: Depends on whether or not they are used. You want to loop over the divs, change their IDs and then find where the IDs are used in code and modify that too? That sounds highly fraught with danger - for example when what you are changing is s substring of something else

Comment: @Sylwek unfortunately no

Comment: So use `js` to change its `name` and `id`. Do all of this tags have same parent tag? How you get this html?

Comment: If the name and ID is not used anywhere there is no need to change it. If it IS used somewhere, then that place has to be changed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use / download this lib [php-simple-html-dom-parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and so try to use this function:

```
public function fixIdNames($html_original) {

        $id_encontrados = [];

        // Create DOM from string
        $html = str_get_html($html_original);

        $a_nodes = $html->find("div[id]");

        foreach ($a_nodes as $key => $element) {

            if (isset($id_encontrados[$element->id])) {
                $id_encontrados[$element->id] = ++$id_encontrados[$element->id];
                $element->id = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $element->id) . $id_encontrados[$element->id];
                //$element->id = 'legal';
            } else {
                $id_encontrados[$element->id] = 1;
            }
        }

        $a_nodes = $html->find("a[name]");

        foreach ($a_nodes as $key => $element) {

            if (isset($id_encontrados[$element->name])) {
                $id_encontrados[$element->name] = ++$id_encontrados[$element->name];
                $element->name = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $element->name) . $id_encontrados[$element->name];
                //$element->id = 'legal';
            } else {
                $id_encontrados[$element->name] = 1;
            }
        }

        return ((string) $html);
    }
```